# ""TypeError: 'Axes3D' object is not subscriptable"" for 3d animation from data

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, mplot3d, matplotlib-animation

I am trying to do a  3D animation using data from two arrays. So I paint 2040 triangles in the 3d plain and I don't want them to change overtime. Then I paint them different colors that I take from another 100 x 2040 array, one color for each triangle. There are 100 moment in time with different colors. So I want my animation to consist of 100 different shots. Is there a way to achieve this using FuncAnimation?
My triangles array - `coords`, colors array - `colors`.

The function `make_triangles` works well for one moment in time, the problem is in the `._offsets3d` part, it gives the error `graph[i]._offsets3d = make_triangle(i, coords, colors) TypeError: 'Axes3D' object is not subscriptable`

Here is my code:

```
def make_triangles(time, coords, colors):
    one_moment_colors = colors.iloc[:, time]
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    ax = Axes3D(fig)
    ax.set_xlim3d(-1, 1)
    ax.set_ylim3d(-1, 1)
    ax.set_zlim3d(-1, 1)
    ax.view_init(0, 10)
    for i in range(int(triangle_amount)):
       one_triangle = coords[i][:][:]
       triangle = Poly3DCollection(one_triangle)
       triangle.set_color(colors.rgb2hex([one_moment_colors.iloc[i].item(), 1 - 
                one_moment_colors.iloc[i].item(), 1 - one_moment_colors.iloc[i].item()]))
       triangle.set_edgecolor('k')
       ax.add_collection3d(triangle)
return fig, ax

def animate_data(i, coords, colors, graph):
    for i in range(100):
        graph[i]._offsets3d = make_triangles(i, coords, colors)
    return graph

def main(coords, colors):
    fig, graph = make_triangles(0, coords, colors)
    iterations = 100
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate_data, iterations, fargs=(coords, colors, graph), interval=50, blit=False, repeat=True)
    plt.show()

main(coords, colors)
```

I was trying to follow this example: https://medium.com/@pnpsegonne/animating-a-3d-scatterplot-with-matplotlib-ca4b676d4b55

I would be very grateful for any suggstions.

Comment: Show us `make_asteroid`. In the example you linked, your `graph[i]` is similar to their `scatters[i]`, which is clearly a list. Your error implies this is not your case.

Comment: I think maybe `make_asteroid == make_triangles`? If so, `graph` is an `Axes3D` object. You then try to loop over `range(100)` and subscript the `Axes3D` object. I'm not sure what you are trying to do there; perhaps you want to iterate over your triangles? in which case, maybe you need something like: `graph.collections[i]`?

Comment: also, you pass `i` into `animate_data` as an argument, but then you don't use that, instead using `for i in range(100)`. I think you can remove the `i` argument from `animate_data`?

Comment: Yes, make_asteroid is make_triangles, I renamed some variables to make it easier to explain my code, but I guess it backfired. I think i am confused as how to change the code from the example to fit into my case. In the example 'scatters' is a list of  points on the graph.  In my case everything is created at once by the 'make_triangles' function.